# onStopped() is not invoked for workmanager

Tags: android, kotlin

I build an app that is able to deploy a periodic work using workmanager and I want to perform some actions like saving key-value in sharePreference or uploading data to firebase when the work is told to be stopped either by users themselves or somehow the system, through overriding the onStopped method. But it doesn't work. I also tested it by setting a button to manually cancel the work using `cancelAllWorkByTag` to check how it works and nothing is working. Can someone help me out?

```
override fun onStopped() {
        super.onStopped()
        val sharedPreferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("AppSharedPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
            putString("working_state", "STOPPED")
            commit()
        }
        val db = Firebase.firestore
        val now = DateTime.now()
        val input = hashMapOf("timestamp" to now.toString(), "stopped" to "the service is somehow stopped")
        db.collection("test").document(now.toString()).set(input, SetOptions.merge())
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the button code you use to cancel the work as well?

Comment: @Putra Nugraha, stop button is quite simple, I just add a function: `val stop = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2) stop.setOnClickListener{ stopWork() }`  ;  `private fun stopWork() { WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWorkByTag("periodicWork") }`; I also try to force to stop in the setting, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you find a workaround @sssbbb?
I cannot do a cleanup / release resources since the work class I created is not aware of when the job finishes.

Comment: Did you get any solution??@sssbbb